# syntax of SELECT INTO

Tags: sql

Hi what is the syntax of SELECT INTO?
I saw the following SQL　code, should the 1st line be

```
SELECT INTO Temp sourceIP,
```

meaning Temp is the new table, and the column sourceIP is written into Temp?

Code:

```
SELECT INTO TempsourceIP,
            AVG(pageRank) AS avgPageRank,
            SUM(adRevenue) AS totalRevenue
FROM Rankings AS R,
     UserVisits AS UV
WHERE R.pageURL = UV.destURL
GROUP BY UV.sourceIP;

SELECT sourceIP,
       totalRevenue,
       avgPageRank
FROM Temp
ORDER BY totalRevenueDESC
LIMIT 1;
```

A further question: is the above code same to creating a view?

```
CREATE VIEW Temp AS
(
SELECT sourceIP,
       .....

);
```

source: Bill Howe's class at coursera.

Comment: what is the dbms that you are referring?

Comment: How many columns are there in the table 'RankingsAS' and 'UserVisitAS' ?

Comment: @MitchWheat i see. thanks. This is a piece of code shown in class. I wonder what's the syntax of SELECT INTO? Is it SELECT INTO new_table column1, column2 ?

Comment: @MitchWheat, not exactly, Postgre and SQLite also have support for limit clauses...

Comment: @Henrique Barcelos: but then it won't make much difference SQL wise, right?

Comment: @MitchWheat IDK, just saying that using `LIMIT` does not imply MySQL, it's an offtopic comment though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SQL, you can copy information from one table into another. The SELECT INTO statement copies data from one table and inserts it into a new table.

for example the following copies all fields of currentTbale to table newTable:

```
SELECT *
INTO newTable
FROM currentTable;
```

for more information go to [SQL_SELECT_INTO](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp).

Comment: Thanks @HaMi. Can it be 
`SELECT INTO newTable column1, column2 
FROM currentTable`
?   See the code in my original post.

Comment: You can do it like SELECT column1, column2 INTO newTable FROM currentTable. the order of statements is important I think :)

Comment: Thank u. the original code i read could have a mistake here. i'll go verify this.

Comment: your welcome my friend :)